# Como capturar de um arquivo.txt nomes completos e números com alphanumericos em Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

Tentei fazer algo assim , porém ele só pega os números depois da / no caso da matricula e o nomes ele só pega o primeiro nome da pessoa e se não tiver acento , e não sei como fazer para ele avaliar tbm os espaços .

Segue o arquivo.txt abaixo e o código:

```
Registro e Acompanhamento de Aulas                                                                                                                                    Universidade de Brasília
                                        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                 |                                          |                    |        |               |         |
                                                                 |                                          |                    |        |               |         |
                                                                 |                                          |                    |        |               |         |
               Atenção                   Código da Disciplina     Nome da Disciplina                             Créditos         Turma    Data da Emissão
                                                                                                                                                           Período
                                                                                                                                                                     Página      Professor(es)


                                         116441                   ENGENHARIA DE SOFTWARE                     004-
                                                                                                                  000-
                                                                                                                       000
                                                                                                                            004   B            07/05/2018  2018/1
                                                                                                                                                                     1           1036602-GENAINA NUNES
    Alunos que não constem nesta                                                                                                                                                 RODRIGUES
    Relação deverão ter sua Situação
    Regularizada na  SAA,  sob Pena     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                         Nome do Departamento    Departamento de Ciência da Computação
                                        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                              |Aulas Ministradas - Rubrica dos
                                                                              |
                                                                              |
                                                                              |
                                                                              ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                            Número da Aula                    |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                                                                                              |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                                                                                              |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  Falta              Alunos                                        Data da    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |
   Número    %      Matrícula     Nome
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    15/0115474    ALEX NASCIMENTO SOUZA

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    15/0115571    ALEXANDRE GONÇALVES TEIXEIRA

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    15/0005539    ANDRE FERNANDES FREIRE

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    15/0005628    ANDREIA DE FREITAS NOVAIS

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    14/0080279    BERNARDO COSTA NASCIMENTO

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    16/0003636    CAIO ALBUQUERQUE BRANDÃO

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    15/0123418    DIOGO QUEIROZ DOS SANTOS

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    14/0038400    EDSON FLORIANO DE SOUSA JUNIOR

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    16/0005523    EMERSON SOUSA CHAVES

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    15/0124163    EMMANUEL GUSTAVO RINALDI PEROTTO

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    12/0044919    FELIPE AUGUSTO RODRIGUES BRANDÃO

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    15/0035187    GABRIEL CAMPOS ALBINO

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    16/0006350    GABRIEL DE SOUSA VIEIRA                               *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    T      R      A      N      C      A      M      E

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    16/0046424    GABRIEL LOBÃO BARROSO DE SOUZA

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    16/0121256    GABRIEL MORAIS MARREIROS

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    15/0010451    GABRIEL VITOR DOS SANTOS CRISPIM

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
  |       |        |             |                                            |               |              |                |               |               |               |                |               |
                    15/0128215    GUILHERME DA SILVA FONTES LOPES

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
















file = File.open("engsoft.txt")
file.each_line do |line|
    #puts line.scan(/\b\d+\b +\b[A-Z][A-Z]+\b/)
    puts line.scan(/\b\d+\b +\b[A-Z][A-Z]+\b +\b\s*\b +\b[A-Z][A-Z]/)
end
```

Comment: Talvez seja mais fácil usar um parser de CSV, usando o `|` como delimitador: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821843